# UIScreen.MainScreen.Brightness not changing Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, uiscreen

I was trying to change the brightness of my iOS app using a text entry box, and I found some stuff online which showed me how to create a dependency service and use UIScreen to set the brightness of the app so that is what I did.
Here is the interface:

```
public interface IBrightnessService
{
    void SetBrightness(float factor);
}
```

Here is the code for actually calling the setBrightness, where I'm doing it based on a Xamarin Entry form(text is inputted, and when enter is pressed this method is called).

```
void Entry_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            var text = ((Entry)sender).Text; //cast sender to access the properties of the Entry
            float value = float.Parse(text);
            var brightnessService = DependencyService.Get<IBrightnessService>();
            brightnessService.SetBrightness((float)value);
        }
```

Here is the implementation in iOS. I tested some stuff, and the value is being sent correctly and the method is being reached, but the line of code `UIScreen.MainScreen.Brightness = brightness;` doesn't actually change UIScreen.MainScreen.Brightness, and I can't seem to figure out why, so was looking for help for this.

```
using Xamarin.Forms;
using UIKit;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof (iOSBrightnessService))]

public class iOSBrightnessService : IBrightnessService
{
    public void SetBrightness(float brightness)
    {
        UIScreen.MainScreen.Brightness = brightness;
    }
}
```

Comment: from the docs: "The value of this property should be a number between 0.0 and 1.0, inclusive."  Are you passing a value in that range?

Comment: @Jason yeah, I am only entering numbers between 0.0 and 1.0

Answer (score 0):

The iPhone simulator brightness is not adjustable, you have to try in a real device!